# Worm Bitten Menados in Europe

Tags: whole-bean, tasting, specialty-coffee

does anyone know, where to get worm bitten menados coffee to be shipped to Europe or to drink in Europe? I would like to try it once but I can't really get my hands on it. Appreciate every help!